# Pull number of cores dynamically in Dockerfile

Tags: python, docker, gunicorn

Currently I am packaging a web application with Docker, and one line in my `Dockerfile` is the following

```
CMD gunicorn -w 4 -b 0.0.0.0:80 main:app
```

I was wondering if its possible to change `-w 4` to something like `-w $(num_cores) * 2 + 1`

How would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're in Linux, you can use the `nproc` command

```
CMD gunicorn -w $(expr $(nproc) \* 2 + 1) -b 0.0.0.0:80 main:app
```